# java cut string after 2 decimal digits?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I have this string

> 17.12121

and I want to save it only as

> 17.12

I have try to use this command :

```
answer = String.format("%.2f", str1);
```

but he give an exception

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

why ?

in the end I wnat the answer to be x.xx

Thanks ,

Comment: `%f` is used to format floating point numbers, not Strings.

Comment: is str1 a String ?

Comment: `answer = String.format("%.2f", Float.valueOf(str1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use float formatting, you could parse your string as a float, and then use `"%.2f`.

If you just want to cut your string two places after the decimal point, you could just find the `.` character and take a substring based on its position.

```
int index = str1.indexOf('.');
if (index >= 0) {
    answer = str1.substring(0, index+3);
} else {
    answer = str1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `%f` you should to have a `float` not a `String`, instead you can use :

```
answer = String.format("%.2f", Float.valueOf(str1));
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Note that the format follow the `Locale`, so the dot can be converted to `,` the result can be `17,12` instead of `17.12` to make sure you get dot you can use Locale.US like this :

```
answer = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Float.valueOf(str1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal d= new BigDecimal("17.12121").setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(d);
```